# how to set tab text colors differently in tablayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

[mytablayout picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENtaw.png)

I wanna set colors blue into 'b', orange into 'c', purple into 'd', red into 'e'.

```
app:tabTextColor="@color/"
```

This xml code change 'all' colors of tab titles so I couldn't use it.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52459143/11647620

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        when (tab.getPosition()) {
            case 0 : {  
                tabLayout.setTabTextColors(otherTabsColor,blueColor);
                tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue));       
                break;
            }

            case 1 : {  
                tabLayout.setTabTextColors(otherTabsColor,orangeColor);
                tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.orange));       
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: using listener! I'll try it thanks @farshad

Comment: I tried it , but `setTabTextColors`  changes all color of tabs

Comment: i edited my code , and now it works :))
tabLayout.setTabTextColors( otherTabsColor , currentTabColor );

in this method first param is other tabs color and second param is current tab color.
pleas try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Comment: how this will set up different color per tab?

Comment: I agree with @snachmsm, this is a vague answer